# How to remove specific FacesMessage from FacesContext?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2.2

How can we delete a specific `FacesMessage` from `FacesContext`. Lets say I have list which contains two FacesMessages whose detail(`getDetail()`) is `Mandatory Fields` and `Invalid Account Number` and I want to delete `Mandatory Fields` `FacesMessage`.

Below is my sample code :

```
ListIterator<?> cmessages = context.getMessageList().listIterator();
cmessages.hasPrevious();
while (cmessages.hasNext() && cmessages!=null) {

    FacesMessage msg =(FacesMessage) ((cmessages.next() instanceof FacesMessage)?cmessages.next():null);
    if(msg!=null){
        if(msg.getDetail().equals(messageDetail)){
              cmessages.next();
              cmessages.remove();
        }
     }
}
```

As my above code also giving me sometimes `UnsupportedOperation` exception

Comment: *"giving me sometimes UnsupportedOperation exception"* Good exceptions already represent the whole answer to the problem. It's just a matter of being able to interpret them. We are able to translate them in layman's terms. It's therefore not helpful if you're hiding all exception detail from those who can translate them for you. Exceptions and stack traces are absolutely not like useless decoration. Be specific and detailed about them.

Comment: Apologies !! `UnsupportedOperation` was reported because I was previously trying to access element unexistent element in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is code snippet I wrote that fixed my issue

```
public static void clearMessagesWithID(String messageID)
{
  String messageDetail = getErrorMessage(messageID);
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  for (Iterator<FacesMessage> iterator = context.getMessages(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    FacesMessage msg = iterator.next();
    if (msg.getDetail().contains(messageDetail)) {
      // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

And that `UnsupportedOperation` was reported because I was previously trying to access element unexistent element in list