# Is it possible to use p:messages and p:message at the same time?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am having trouble finding an example of this in the primefaces documentation.

What I have is a very long form. For each component in the form I do have

```html
<p:message for="abc"/>
```

but what I would also like to have is a single p:message at the top of the page that would say something like : "You are missing one or more required fields. Please scroll below etc etc etc"

If I add

```html
<p:messages/>
```

to the top of the page ALL the fields and their required messages show up. That makes the form even more ugly than it already is.

So is there a way to detect if there is at least one required/validation error and then display something at the top of the page like my example instead of all the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a phase listener to check if validation failed, and if so, add a global message. This global message can be displayed using:

```html
<p:messages globalOnly="true"/>
```

See also:

- [Add global message when field validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247737/add-global-message-when-field-validation-fails)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jasper however due to limitations out of my control I cannot utilize Omnifaces. Would there be another alternative using strictly only JSF perhaps?

Comment: @TarPatel I've added a plain vanilla JSF option to the answer in the linked question.