# Custom Validator for p:selectOneMenu make it not working rendering / not rendering other components

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this select:

```xhtml
<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{bean.val}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="X" itemLabel="Select" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getVals()}" />
    <p:ajax update="wrapper" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And this is the wrapper it updates:

```xhtml
<p:panel id="wrapper">
    <p:panel rendered="#{bean.val == 'A' or bean.val == 'B'}">
        <!-- insert your code here -->
    </p:panel> 
</p:panel>
```

The wrapper is outside the select, at the same level.

At the start, it's all ok. The wrapper is hidden.

If I select 'A' and then 'C', for example, the wrapper disappear. **BUT**, if I select 'A' or 'B' and **'X' again** (the first "choice", Select), the wrapper does **NOT disappear!**

I have put a **breakpoint** inside the **setter** of `bean.val`. The setter in invoked for all the choices **BUT** for the **first one** the value inside the debugger is the same as the **previous** one!

BUT! If I **remove** the **validator**, it **works**!

This is the validator:

```java
@FacesValidator(value="requiredSelect")
public class RequiredSelect implements Validator {
    protected MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil();
    
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        String val = (String) value;
        
        if ("X".equals(val)) {
            FacesMessage msg = this.messageUtil.getDefaultValidationError();
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Previously I used **another** validator:

```java
@FacesValidator(value="requiredString")
public class RequiredString implements Validator {
    protected MessageUtil messageUtil = new MessageUtil();
    
    @Override
    public void validate(
        FacesContext context, 
        UIComponent component, 
        Object value
    ) throws ValidatorException {
        String val = (String) value;
        
        if (val == null || val.trim().isEmpty()) {
            FacesMessage msg = this.messageUtil.getDefaultValidationError();
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

but it did **not** work, because the **empty string** was **not** saved to the backing bean at menu change. So, if, for example, you selected 'A' and then back '' (Select) and you try to submit the form, the select is signaled with errors, **but** the **value** of the select returns to be **'A'**! So the bogus 'X' value.

I'm using Primefaces 3.4.1 and Mojarra 2.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a bit of a XY-problem. You are trying to hack your way out of creating a required `p:selectOneMenu` using the `X` select item. This requires you to create a validator. If you simply make the  `p:selectOneMenu` required, and would use `null` as the `itemValue` of the placeholder, it prevents the need to handle the `X`, so you don't need a validator.

Selecting `null` will cause validation to fail. So, once a selection is made you no longer want to render the `null` placeholder. Normally  one would use the `hideNoSelectionOption` attribute of the `p:selectOneMenu`. But this is not available in PrimeFaces 3.4.1. As you don't want to upgrade, you can add this behavior by creating a custom renderer for the `SelectOneMenu`.

Create a new class, say `my.custom.MySelectOneMenuRenderer`, and extend `SelectOneMenuRenderer`. In this you want to `@Override` the `encodeInput` method to something like:

```java
protected SelectItem selectMeOption = new SelectItem(null, "Select");

@Override
protected void encodeInput(
    FacesContext context, SelectOneMenu menu, String clientId,
    List<SelectItem> selectItems, Object values, Object submittedValues,
    Converter converter
) throws IOException {
    String classes = menu.getStyleClass();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bnormalSelect\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(classes);
    boolean isNormal = matcher.find();
    Object value = menu.getValue();
    
    // If there's not a class "normalSelect" and no value is set, add the
    // null option as the first item
    if (!isNormal) {
        if (value == null) {
            selectItems.add(0, selectMeOption);
        }
        else {
            SelectItem firstOption = selectItems.get(0);
            
            if (selectMeOption.equals(firstOption)) {
                selectItems.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
    
    super.encodeInput(
        context, menu, clientId, selectItems, values, submittedValues,
        converter
    );
}
```

Add your custom renderer to the `render-kit` section in your `faces-config.xml` like:

```xml
<render-kit>
  <renderer>
    <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.SelectOneMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>my.custom.MySelectOneMenuRenderer</renderer-class>
  </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

View example:

```xhtml
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.val}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.vals()}" />
    <p:ajax update="#{empty bean.val ? '@this' : ''}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

For a working example see: https://github.com/jepsar/primefaces-test/blob/so_68457571/src/main/webapp/test.xhtml

See also:

- [How to sort f:selectItems in each p:selectOneMenu of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093299/how-to-sort-fselectitems-in-each-pselectonemenu-of-my-application)

Comment: It works. You forgot to say to re-apply `<p:ajax update="#{empty bean.val ? '@this' : ''}" />` ;-)

Comment: Great! BTW, custom attributes are a more elegant way of controlling the renderer's behavior IMO. And you can better do `<p:ajax update="@this" rendered=#{empty bean.val}" />` (saves you Ajax requests when the value is set).

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the JSF Life-Cycle for example here:
https://www.torsten-horn.de/img/JSF-Lifecycle.gif

And you will note, that if you throw "Validator-Exceptions" the "Update Model Values" Phase is skipped. (Process Events forwards to render response).

Hence your value "X", which you consider invalid in your validator is never send to the bean, and therefore the wrapper won't vanish.

What you actually want is:

- Define a proper "NoSelect-Option"
- Make the field "required".

Then - upon submission - the required field will be considered empty and throw a validator-exception where you need it.

ps.: A neat way to just bypass this "Issue" is to use `hideNoSelectionOption` on the `selectOneMenu` - that way, the form starts with "Please select", but the user can't switch back to "Please select", once he made an choice:

```
<p:selectOneMenu  value="#{bean.val}" hideNoSelectionOption="#{not empty bean.val}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getVals()}" />
    <p:ajax update="@this,wrapper" process="@this" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Updated, added `@this` to `p:ajax`.

PS: this does not work with old versions of Primefaces that does not have `hideNoSelectionOption`

Comment: @JasperdeVries No, the NoSelect-Option is valid to be selected. It just will cause validation-Errors, when the form is submitted and the field is "required". That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: The problem is I can't customize the `require="true"` message

Comment: @MarcoSulla you can. Use `required="true" requiredMessage="This field is required, bro!"`

Comment: @JasperdeVries No, "Required" validation does happen up on submission, not on Postback. Reason "his" validator is causing this issue, because he is evaluating his "own designed" required-validation ON postback, where it only should happen on submission.

Comment: I do not want to add the same requiredMessage="This field is required, bro!" for ***ALL*** inputs, for the One Source of Truth principle. Can't I change the default message?

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155684/change-the-default-message-validation-error-value-is-required-to-just-value I'll try

Comment: PS: the "neat way" is not neat, because the user could never change the select.

Comment: Please take a look at my elaboration[1] of your answer and the latest comments: the problem is even if I put null and/or noSelectionOption, the wrapper is NOT updated if I select an option and then back the noSelectionOption.

PS: someone can call BalusC? X-D

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483393/1763602

Comment: @MarcoSulla if it's a mandatory field, the user has no need to switch back to "Please select..."

Comment: The problem is I can't use your "trick", because I have Primefaces 3.4.1 and no `hideNoSelectionOption`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is my solution, thanks to the [dognose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057547/dognose)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68471915/1763602) first part:

1. Change the input to:

```xhtml
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.val}" required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getVals()}" />
    <p:ajax update="wrapper" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

No need to `itemValue="#{none}"`, since null strings are automatically transformed to empty string by default, by jboss or primefaces, I do not remember. No need of `noSelectionOption="true"` too (I do not understand its scope... the validation works even if I don't put it)

2. added to a package `my.package` the files `messages.properties`, with this content:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = Error
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED_detail = One or more fields are missing or wrong. Please check the form
```

3. Then I added a `p:messages` like this one:

```xhtml
<p:messages id="messages" closable="true" showDetail="true" />
```

4. Then, I used [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68396432/1763602) to remove the duplicate messages.

Comment: Try selecting a value first and then select the empty "Select" option.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I tried, it works. I submitted with "Select" and it was red. I Changed to a value, I submitted and it was "white". Then I changed again to "Select" and submitted and it returned red.

Comment: Is the wrapper also updated in that case?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Uops. No.... I try null and/or noSelectionOption :D

Comment: @JasperdeVries: I tried with all the combinations of null and noSelectionOption, nothing. The wrapper does not udated, probably because the setter is NOT invoked

Comment: @JasperdeVries but this problem is only with my version of Primefaces, or was fixed?

Comment: It's not a bug. If you provide an empty value for a required field, processing will fail. That's why I remove the "Select" option once a valid selection is made in my answer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: In an HTML page, it's possible to do it. So making this complicated code that does not work for me for something so simple sounds to me a bug to report. And I never get so much votes for a question on JSF :D

Comment: HTML does not do server side validation.

Comment: @JasperdeVries No, but you can use Spring and Hibernate validators. More easy.